# Hardware recommendation for a web 2.0 site using drupal

Tags: web-server, performance, hardware, drupal

We are working in a new website (a typical web 2.0 website). We are going to
use drupal and mysql. We expect to have an estimated traffic of 2000 users per day (perhaps 200 - 300 new users per day). 
Based on your experience, could you recommend the adecuate hardware to support this?
We can have 2 separate servers (for MySQL and for Apache).

Thanks,

Ezequiel.

EDIT: Basically site will serve a lot of static information. Also will contain a blogging section. 
EDIT2: Information won´t change so frequently, lot of queries are expected because of drupal.

Comment: How long is a piece of a string?  More information is required.  What is the site going to be doing/serving?  Lots of files?  Just basic page impressions?

Comment: Will it be like the StackOverflow traffic? Will it serve high updates, lots of queries, etc?

Comment: Product and service recommendations are specifically off topic for ServerFault (see point 4 in the NOT About section of the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used to work for an e-commerce company. We had in the vicinity of several hundred thousand unique visitors per day, most of whom visited on average around 10 pages. This website was run off 2 x 1U Dell PowerEdge 1750 with 2GB RAM, SCSI RAID1 drives (web servers, Debian, Apache) and 1 x 2U Dell PowerEdge 2950 with 4GB RAM and SCSI RAID10 drive(databases, Debian, MySql).

If you translate this back into your situation, I would suggest that just about any 1U server will do the trick for you, if configured correctly. There are probably plenty of people here that will scream in horror, but realistically anything more than your plain vanilla 1U server would be just overkill in your situation.

As traffic increases, you'll get the biggest boost out of separating the database from the web server (saves a lot of context switching).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the "[resourceful hosting](http://drupal.org/node/190070)" document on the Drupal site. Even though the document was targeted for the year 2008, I think they have a good baseline to help you understand what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Drupal is highly relational so MySQL will bear the brunt of the performance hit so I'd spec accordingly.

Thankfully the Drupal community has come up with lots of strategies to overcome some of Drupal's scalability shortcomings.

For example, use of the memcache module (http://drupal.org/project/memcache) to get the cache tables out of the database.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Project Mercury](http://www.chapterthree.com/blog/josh_koenig/project_mercury_preconfigured_drupalvarnish_ec2_ami) for this- it bundles a couple different performance enhancements (Pressflow Drupal + APC for PHP + Varnish for handling anonymous users) into one convenient EC2 Amazon Machine Image.  It's late in the Alpha stage, but you can spin it up for dev pretty cheaply on Amazon and pick up config tips for your own hardware there.